# Remove title from single tab in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I am trying to remove the title/label from only one of five tabs, using React Navigation. I know that `showLabel: false` will remove the label from all tabs, but I am looking to remove just one. If I set `title; ''`, it will insert an empty string, but will take up space. This is the tab from which I'd like to remove the title:

```
AddThing: {
  screen: AddThing,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: <Image source={addThing} />,
  },
},
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No. I ended up removing the title from all of them.

Answer (score 0):

just set the title to "" like this

```
  export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Earn,
    Shop,
    Adding: {
      screen: () => null, // Empty screen
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: <Plus />, // Plus button component
        title: '',
      }),
    },
    Learn,
    More,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bottom tab navigator as shown in the code snippet. Add a listener to the navigator component and listen for state changes as you move from a tab to another tab.

Follow the comments in the code as you implement yours.

```
...

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Navigator = () => {
//Add a state to store the focused screen on tab press
 const [routeName, setRouteName] = useState('');

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenListeners={{

        state: (e) => {
/** 
Listen for navigator state change and 
store the name of the focused screen 
**/
          setRouteName(e.data['state']['routeNames'][e.data['state']['index']]);
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name='Home'
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={({ route }) => {
         //here is the application. Pretty straight forward
          return {
            title: route.name === routeName ? route.name : '',
          };
        }}
      />

...
```

Comment: Please add description to go along with your code snippet.

Comment: This should help @AhmadKhudeish